# Asp.Net notification application using signalR to send notification to only one client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, notifications, signalr

I am trying to make a notification application using SignalR in which only one specific user gets the notification. How do I do this using SignalR? Or is there another way to make a similar feature with any other technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  See the link here [SignalR wiki - Hub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs)

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
     public void Send(string data)
     {


         // Similar to above, the more verbose way
         Clients[Context.ConnectionId].addMessage(data);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could broadcast a message to a particular client knowing his id:

```
var connection = Connection.GetConnection<MyConnection>();
connection.Broadcast(clientId, "some message to broadcast");
```

UPDATE
Check the documentation for up to date syntax https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

Comment: Hi, But i can use unique connection id? its change connectionid every time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the API has been updated. Here is how you send a message to the calling client.

```
Clients.Caller.addContosoChatMessageToPage(name, message);
```

From [Hubs API Guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients)

Comment: I had a very similar problem and this is the perfect answer. Thanks!

(I should note that I was using SignalR 2.0.)